# missing shared regex library, but yum package for it is already installed

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a binary written in C++ on Centos 8 that gives the following error when executed:

```
$ prog
prog: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried installing libboost_regex but I get a message that it is already there:

```
$ sudo yum install boost-regex
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:35 ago on Wed 10 Nov 2021 12:40:18 AM UTC.
Package boost-regex-1.66.0-7.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Reaching back into old memories, I ran this command on a hunch:

```
$ ldconfig -p| grep regex
    libboost_regex.so.1.69.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libboost_regex.so.1.69.0
    libboost_regex.so.1.66.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libboost_regex.so.1.66.0
    libboost_regex.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libboost_regex.so
```

Obviously 1.69.0 != 5, but I'm not sure what to make of the above output. What else can I do?

Comment: Well, where did the binary come from?

Comment: Old CentOS 5 binary ?? .... I.e. `libboost_regex.so.5` is provided by the year 2009 boost **1.41** . ( Package name was `boost141-regex` ).

Comment: Indeed, 'corporate archeology' some call it. Would it be easier to just rewrite the code?

Comment: @KnudLarsen does libfoo.so.X always imply version X of the OS?

Comment: libfoo.so.X version : Version "5" is a unique numbering for the "extra packages" `boost141-xxx` for CentOS **4** and CentOS 5 . All default boost has like libboost_regex.so.1.68.0, i.e. the boost version numbering.

Comment: Repo example, boost141 , baseurl =  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/xtreemfs/CentOS_5/ .............. Packages http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/xtreemfs/CentOS_5/x86_64/